# Не срабатывает BroadcastReceiver "action.USER_PRESENT"

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver, экран

Приветствую Вас! Пытаюсь зарегистрировать событие разблокировки экрана устройства. Вешаю ресивер с `action = "android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"`.

Когда приложение активно - все работает. Когда выкидываю приложение из шторки недавно запущенных - не срабатывает. Причем эта проблема наблюдается с API21(на 4.4. - все работает). Вроде как ожидаемо, гугл с 21 апи очень серьезно занялся оптимизацией работы фоновых приложений, но как-то же этот ресивер должен работать?

Код манифеста:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.appdroid.develop.receiverscreenlock">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".ScreenReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Код класса `ScreenReceiver`:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "myLog";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onReceive "+ intent.getAction());
        Toast.makeText(context,"unlock screen",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: этот ресивер входит в перечень тех из них, кои не работают из манифеста. Его нужно создавать в коде активити. Хотя не факт, что проблемы на этом закончатся

Comment: Вы не правы. Этот ресивер без проблем работает из манифеста. Проблема несрабатывания ресивера в том, что андроид (как я написал выше) начиная с версии 5.0 серьезно занялся оптимизации ресурса батареи. Эта оптимизация и убивает приемник.